# Bluetooth device connected to Ubuntu 22.04: Sound for video but not for call

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire

I'm working with Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS, trying to get the sound from an Android phone connected to is.

The bluetooth connection is ok. The Android see the connection, but only for multimedia and not for call:

- The sound from the video played on the Android is played on the Ubuntu
- The sound from any call from the phone is not played on the Ubuntu

I managed to make it work on an "old" debian version. It was working with pulseaudio and ofono. Now Ubuntu is working with pipewire, and it seems to have change a lot of things. But I haven't found what to configure to make sound from call working

The profile under pulseaudio to select was headset_audio_gateway

Edit: After installing wireplumber, the connection to the bluetooth device is not working anymore with the following error:
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable

Thank you